# Does an eBay listing that accepts Bitcoin violate their payments policy?

Tags: ecommerce, payment

eBay's payments policy says that the listing must accept at least one payment method that is PayPal, credit card, etc.   It does not appear to say that other payment methods cannot be offered though.

- http://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/accepted-payments-policy.html

Would a listing that has in the description something like the following be a violation of that policy?

> Also will accept Bitcoin for payment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under "Payment methods not allowed on eBay" we can see:

> - Send cash or money orders through instant, **point-to-point cash transfer services (that are not banks)** such as Western Union or MoneyGram
> - Pay using online or other payment methods **not specifically permitted** in this policy

So we have two points against using Bitcoins, technically making it a violation of that policy. This question, however, would be better asked directly to eBay.

Comment: I would like to add to this that Paypal (owned by eBay, and is the primary and virtually only payment method used on eBay) has been participating in on-going actions against the Bitcoin community.

They frequently close accounts and reverse transactions by anyone who buys or sells Bitcoin, and eBay frequently closes auctions involving Bitcoin. For some reason they have not taken action against Casascius coins though.